# Clone Div into another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I am trying to clone a DIV to prevent data reputation; this is a frequent thing I want to do over various pages so I don't want to make bug structural changes.

I would like to Clone mApageLeft with the class maContent, and all of its inner div's and content into another div named cloneContent.

I have looked at other examples of Clone, and my attempt does not show anything.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
           <div id="mApageLeft" name="mApageLeft" class="maContent">
                  <div> header and some text here
                  </div>
                  <div>  text and image here
                  </div>
                  <div>  text and another image here
                  </div>
           </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="mobileArea">
<div id="mobileMainArea">
    headers, links and sme text
            <div name="cloneContent" id="cloneContent" class="maContent"></div>
            <script>
            $(function(){
                var $mainAreaClone = $('#mApageLeft').clone();
                $('#cloneContent').html($mainAreaClone);
            });
            </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no problem with it, works here: http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/1/

Comment: did you include jQuery library file in the page? is there any error in your browser console

Comment: what is meant by data reputation..?

Comment: your code is working,

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, could it be because its a PHP page?

Comment: If you are using a standered browser after you view the page right click and click inspect element to view(Chrome or Firefox hopefully) the debug window , click console on that and check for any errors showing up , this could be probably coz your jquery is not loaded or its too old.

Comment: Apologies to waste all your time, it was the Jquery link.  Thank you all for your help, time and teaching.

Comment: no worries , we all make mistakes (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine when I test it on fiddle. Even after that, if you wanna try something else, you can try `append()` instead of `html()` function. Usually when you clone, you want to append the cloned object, you don't want to put is as inner `HTML`. However, that will also work.